# Teradata Express Studio 16.2, filtering schemas that are not accessible

Tags: teradata

For Teradata Studio Express 16.2, How do 
I filter out all schemas I do not have access to?

My user account only has access to 2 database schemas but it is showing way more than that as you can see from the image below (Even shows all the user's db):

[image]

Comment: Check the options in the *Data Source Explorer Load Preferences* settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple options:
From the menu bar at the top of the screen...
Window -> Preferences -> Teradata Datatools Preferences -> Data Source Explorer Load Preferences.  Then there are option buttons that let you pick.

Another easy way is to right click on the "Databases" folder in the Data Source Explorer and select "filter".  You can then define your own filter rule for which databases should be displayed.

Note:  I am using version 16.10.1.201708101349 but I think yours should be the same